# How can I mock in deno my mongodb database/client?

Tags: mongodb, testing, mocking, deno

I was trying to write some unit tests and mock some functions that make network calls and more. I see that Deno's testing module only provides asserts to work with.
Is there a good library or something I can use for Deno to make mocks for tests?

Best regards
Thnaks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no mocking functionality in the Deno Standard Library (`std`) but you can find a few libraries/modules/frameworks that provide mocking on `deno.land/x`. [Rhum](https://drash.land/rhum/v1.x/#/tutorials/mocks), for example, provides mocks. Here's an example from their docs:

```js
class ToBeMocked { ... }

const mock = Rhum
  .mock(ToBeMocked)
  .withConstructorArgs("someArg") // if the class to be mocked has a constructor and it requires args
  .create();
```

Keep in mind that most Deno modules are still being actively developed so they may not have every piece of functionality just yet. I don't know if any of Node's testing frameworks work on Deno, but if so you could use one of those (Jest/Jasmine/Mocha etc.)